# Android Database query

Tags: android, sqlite

I have application, which downloads data from internet and is supposed to write it to DB using content provider.

```
private void addCurrency(Currency _currency){
    ContentResolver cr=getContentResolver();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();    

    values.put(CurrencyProvider.KEY_DATE, _currency.getDate().getTime());
    values.put(CurrencyProvider.KEY_NAME, _currency.getName());
    values.put(CurrencyProvider.KEY_NOMINAL, _currency.getNominal());
    values.put(CurrencyProvider.KEY_VALUE, _currency.getValue());

    String w=CurrencyProvider.KEY_NAME+" = "+_currency.getName();
    if (cr.query(CurrencyProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, w,null , null).getCount()==0){
        cr.insert(CurrencyProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    }else
        cr.update(CurrencyProvider.CONTENT_URI, values, w, null);
}
```

So, I'm trying either to update record if it exists, or to add new.
But I'm getting SQLite exception:
near "доллар": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM currency WHERE (name = Австралийский доллар)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try surrounding your name with quote

```
String w=CurrencyProvider.KEY_NAME+" = '"+_currency.getName() + "'";
```